# how to fix Leverage browser caching nginx?

Tags: caching, nginx, browser-cache

I went to the Internet, put all the possible settings for caching, but all the same the end of google page sped insights wrote that I do not have caching for these files how to fix this?

[image: Shiw picture]

my cache settings "nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

```
 proxy_temp_path /var/nginx/proxy_temp;
 add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
 proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:100m;
 proxy_cache one;
 proxy_cache_valid any 30d;
 proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri$cookie_US;
```

my server conf "nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/theband"

```
location ~* ^(?!/media).*.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
    expires 365d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
}
location ~* ^(?!/static).*.(?:css|js|html)$ {
    expires 365d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    proxy_cache one;
    proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"expires 35d;" this line need to remove, from where you defined it to create the storage of your files.

from here:

```
   location ~* ^(?!/media).*.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        root /tmp/nginx/trash/trash_media;
        expires 35d; # REMOVE THISSSSSSSS
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        access_log off;
    }
```

To here:

```
server {

    listen   80;
    server_name myip;
    expires 35d;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
```

> and it will work, although in all absolutely examples, you do not
>   need to put storage time there !!!!!!

also don't forget to allow  accept data from net and write and read it from local storage

```
sudo chown www-data /tmp/nginx/proxy_temp
sudo chmod 700 /tmp/nginx/proxy_temp
sudo chown www-data /tmp/nginx/cache
sudo chmod 700 /tmp/nginx/cache
sudo chown www-data /tmp/nginx/cache2
sudo chmod 700 /tmp/nginx/cache2
```

Comment: yeah man, i feel your pain! also thank you i can't solve that))

Comment: @JaneDow I'm happy to repay you the same)) you helped a lot, so I helped you))

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by moving expires from server block

```
server {
    expires 35d;
    ...
}
```

to the parent http block

```
http {
    expires 35d;
    ...
}
```

"Context:   http, server, location, if in location" shows it can reside in these blocks.  not sure why mine didn't work in server or location.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html?&_ga=2.49684582.1104146524.1536596059-1026560835.1535666041#expires